# Quick link to tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, domain-name

badp seems hell-bent on making sprays for TF2 for the sake of advertising the site, but he was remarking how long the domain name is, e.g.

> [image]
>   [Why do we have to have such a longass domain name :|](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/930997#930997)
>   I wanted to make a promotional TF2 spray but no one is going to type that URL from a spray
>
> [much later...]
>
> [image]
>   [I mean, our domain name makes this kind of stuff useless, but seriously...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/957693#957693)
>
> — badp

Could another level be added to the domain name so something like:
**tf2.gaming.stackexchange.com** or **gaming.stackexchange.com/tf2** (I'd guess that tags that collide with existing directories are rare) would redirect to **gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2**?  It's not a massive improvement, but it's still an improvement that still retains the brand versus using some random URL shortening service.

It seems like this would work fine pretty much anywhere, **python.stackoverflow.com**, etc.

Comment: [Roughly the same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58741/stack-overflow-tag-filtered-subsites) as a Meta Stack Overflow request for different reasons. Not yet declined, so let's see what the community here thinks of this one.

Comment: random URL shortening: j.mp/gamingSE

Comment: `gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[tf2]` is equivalent to, and slightly shorter than, `gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2`. But it's still long.

Comment: The site's name is a bigger problem, imo. If we bought [se.com](http://se.com), which hasn't had any content for 3 years, like proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63618/138509), that would help a lot.

Comment: @Ullallullo - I was about to suggest that myself. I agree.

Comment: @Ullallullo I think the main reason for a _two letters .com domain_ having no content for three years is that the owner's just waiting for somebody to pour a couple bajillion dollars into it, while paying much smaller fees to keep it up.

Answer (score 5):

I've got one for you:

http://q-a.vg

Or oh so more specifically: http://tf2.q-a.vg

That does feel right now doesn't it?

I took the liberty of setting some more up:

- http://sc2.q-a.vg
- http://mc.q-a.vg
- http://df.q-a.vg

Comment: I wish I could give this answer a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd much rather get something like:

> `gaming.stackexchange.com/q/tf2`

Such a format would be ambiguous with purely numeric tags, but I don't think there's any in the network...

...but that's really not the point. The point is, no one is going to type out an URL from an ingame spray. Not a url *that* long anyway.

What I'll try next is use sprays to show useful snippets of information. Public Service Announcements, if you will. This is better karma, because the sprays actually inform, rather than piquing curiosity. I feel this is more aligned to our purposes of making the world a better place.

[image: People bumping into my toys are either me, or spies. When in doubt, shoot.]

...[when I do fix this quality problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21929/why-do-my-tf2-sprays-look-like-crap), that is.

Comment: Why not just **gaming.stackexchange.com/tf2**?  The likelyhood of a tag colliding with some useful subdirectory seems minimal

Comment: Or maybe **/t/tf2** for no chance of collisions?

Answer (score 1):

I think something likes `python.stackoverflow.com` looks **awesome** - it really gives the feeling of a python-dedicated site; but it's a bit on the cheating side, since it's *not* a python-dedicated site.

Plus, it breaks a bit the URL convention, since tf2.gaming.stackexchange.com is not really a subdomain of gaming, it's the same site, just a specific page on it.

Comment: URL conventions have been outdated since Al Gore invented them :P